# Join Datatable with List<object> to form a new Datatable using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Join between Datatable "CTIN" column should happen with List gstin property, so the final datatable output should include the new column "Status" as 4th column in datatable.

```
class EInvoice
{
    public string gstin { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<EInvoice> itemList = new List<EInvoice>();
        itemList.Add(new EInvoice() { gstin = "A1234", Status = "Y" });
        itemList.Add(new EInvoice() { gstin = "B1234", Status = "N" });
        itemList.Add(new EInvoice() { gstin = "C1234", Status = "N" });
        itemList.Add(new EInvoice() { gstin = "D1234", Status = "Y" });

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("CTIN");
        dt.Columns.Add("Buyer");
        dt.Columns.Add("Seller");

        dt.Rows.Add("A1234", "Rakesh", "Prasad");
        dt.Rows.Add("B1234", "Bikash", "Prasad");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Join between Datatable "CTIN" column should happen with List gstin property, so the final datatable output should include the new column "Status" as 4th column in datatable.
Datatable should contain all the existing 3 columns and a new "Status" column from the List. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Join between Datatable "CTIN" column should happen with List gstin property, so the final datatable output should include the new column "Status" as 4th column in datatable.

Comment: You already wrote that in the question text, but that's not a question yet. You didn't ask a question. Right now it's as if you're asking people to write the code for you. Have you tried something? Encountered a problem? Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: The duplicate shows how you can use [LINQ to Datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/cross-table-queries-linq-to-dataset) to query any DataTable as if it was an IEnumerable and join it with any other IEnumerable